# Play framework issue with Mysql

Tags: mysql, playframework

I have created basic CURD application using Play framework. It is working perfectly fine in my current machine. When I am trying to run the same application from my friend machine it is working but it is unable to store data into Database. It is just storing null values in Database.

I have followed same configuration in same Machine and I have used MySql as my Database.

Comment: Some code would be nice... My psychic ability is switched off this evening...

Comment: Agree with @dave to show some code, but on top of my head: does the MySql user have privileges to write data?